# How to know if a web-site is developed/running using a specific technology?

Tags: content-management-system

Since many front-end frameworks/CMS have a fully customizable appearance, I would like to know how is the best/easiest way to determine or identify if some web-site is developed or running with a specific technology.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wappalyzer browser extension is the best way to know the technology behind a website.

And to discover if it's build with Liferay or any other way.

https://wappalyzer.com/

Comment: Actually I checked the sesame street page and it returned all the technologies involved, including Liferay. 

I did not know this plugging, thank you ver much for your response. +1